# Show that the inverse function also satisfies C-R equation.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, cauchy-riemann-equations

Suppose that a smooth function $f=\left(f_{1}, f_{2}\right): \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ satisfies the following property:

1. $$
   \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial y}, \quad \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x}
   $$
   Prove that, if the Jacobian matrix $D f(x, y) \neq 0,$ then $f$ is locally invertible and the inverse function also satisfies property (1).

**My try:** $f$ is locally invertible by Inverse function theorem. Consider $f (x, y)=\left(f_{1}(x, y), f_{2}(x, y)\right)=(z, \omega): \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$
$\Rightarrow f^{-1}(z, \omega)=f^{-1} f(x, y)=(x, y)$
$\Rightarrow g(z, \omega)=(x, y).$
$\Rightarrow\left(g_{1}(z, \omega), g_{2}(z, \omega)\right)=(x, y).$
Observe that, if we consider,
$$
\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x} \neq 0 \neq \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial y}
$$
Now we have,

$1=\frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x }=\frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial z} \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x}$
$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x}\right)}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial y}\right)}$

and again

$1=\frac{\partial g_{2}}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial g_{2}}{\partial \omega} \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial g_{2}}{\partial \omega} \frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial y} \Rightarrow \frac{\partial g_{2}}{\partial \omega}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial y}\right)}.$

$\therefore$ we have,

$$\frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial g_{2}}{\partial \omega}.$$

$1=\frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial \omega}\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial \omega} \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial \omega} \frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x}\Rightarrow \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial \omega}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x}\right)}=-\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial y}\right)}.$

$1=\frac{\partial g_{2}}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial g_{2}}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial g_{2}}{\partial z} \frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial y}.$

$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial g_{2}}{\partial y z}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\partial f_{i}}{\partial y}\right)}
$
So, we have $\frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial \omega}=-\frac{\partial g_{2}}{\partial z}$

What will happen if either of $\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x}$ or $\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial y}
$ is zero?
I don't think that here we are allowed to use complex analysis because it was one of our advanced calculus question where it is assumed that we don't now complex analysis.

Comment: The Jacobian matrix of the inverse is the inverse of The original jacobian so the property should follow from the way you write the inverse of a two by two matrix (the main diagonal is interchanged up to the determinant, so the first C_r eq follows, while the off diagonal change sign up to the determinant, so second C-r also follows)

Comment: Can you please elaborate? $f \circ f^{-1}=id$ so we have $D(f)\times D(f^{-1})=id$ matrix then $D(f^{-1})=D(f)^{-1}$ then what?

Comment: do you know how to compute the inverse of a $2\times2$ matrix? - you switch the main diagonal and preserve the off-diagonal with changed signs while dividing all by the determinant - see that works and then that C-R follow immediately

Comment: Yeah, I have checked. It worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help  - no problem